# auto-import entire folder in nuxt 3 (server side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt3, auto-import, nitro

I need to import all script files inside a server folder `server/models`

and i tried these inside `nuxt.config` file:

```
  nitro: {
    plugins: ['~/server/index.ts'],
    scanDirs: ['~/server/models']
  },
  imports: {
    dirs: [
      '~/server/models',
      // '~/server/models/**',
    ],
    global: true
  }
```

also defined modules like:

```
(options, nuxt) => {
      const { resolve } = createResolver(import.meta.url)
      addServerImportsDir(resolve('./server/models'))
      // nuxt.hooks.hook('nitro:config', (config) => {
      //   config.plugins = config.plugins || []
      //   config.plugins.push(resolve('server/models'))
      // })
}
```

but none of them imported exported model files automatically and globally for server codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is server-side, nest the `imports` inside `nitro` option. And do not use `~`, but a relative route:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    imports: {
      dirs: [
        './server/helpers'
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Note, it is also possible to use `/server/utils` that gets autoimported out-of-the-box.

Comment: it worked thanks ... is there a way i get export or files names list inside that folder?